# Can an iOS app be installed on zillions of devices without paying the App Store yearly subscription?

Tags: ios, app-store, mdm

I have finished an iOS app for the company I work. I have a paid app store account for my own particular apps.

The company wants to distribute this app to zillions of their customers without paying anything to Apple.

Their idea: we will distribute it by using MDM.

Will this work?

Will an app that is simply installed on their test device work if they copy the binary image of that device using MDM to other devices? I don't think so.

As far as I know you first have to create a signed IPA for distribution, using a paid account. They think they can simply install the app on the device using Xcode and they copy the device's binary image to other devices.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Are your zillions of customers willing to install an MDM profile from your company?

Comment: I feel your pain. Your pain in mine. My boss has this idea that they will install manually all copies on all customer's devices...

Comment: App binaries need to be signed and have a valid provisioning profile.  When you create an ad-hoc build the provisioning profile includes the devices in your developer account (a maximum of 100 devices), so that is your first limitation.  Ad-hoc builds are only valid for 6months or so and they stop working, so that is your second limitation.  Only Apple can sign an app that works on any device for ever.  This is for apps distributed via the App Store, which means your app will need to pass review.  You can't provide the app directly to your customers even after you pay the $99

Comment: I think I read you could distribute it using your own servers but again, you have to pay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using MDM will work. Check out this page:

https://support.apple.com/guide/mdm/mdm-overview-mdmbf9e668/web

> You can then wirelessly distribute, manage, and configure apps and books purchased through Apple School Manager or Apple Business Manager.

AFAIK you still need to enroll in the Apple Developer Program (where the $99 per year comes from) to publish to those channels.

Comment: Thanks. I was suspecting that.